# Installing specific versions via stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, cabal-install, ghc-mod

So I suppose the problem I'm really trying to solve is that when I run ghc-mod I get this error:

`CabalHelper/Licenses.hs|53 col 18 error| error: Ambiguous occurrence ‘lookupInstalledPackageId’`

I found this relevant issue:
https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod/issues/772

Where it suggests installing ghc-mod from github,
I'd like to do everything via stack if possible (just to avoid mixing too many environments), but I couldn't find a way to specify either a version or how to specify a github repo with `stack install`.

I also continually run into errors from stack saying that it found version `x` when version `y` was required, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to install version `x` anyways.

Anyone know how I can install the latest version of `ghc-mod`? Preferably with `stack`.

Comment: Specify the github repo in your [`stack.yaml`](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/yaml_configuration.md) file (see esp. "complex package locations").

Comment: I'd like to download it as a binary for global use on my system, any ideas there?

Answer (score 4):

This was implemented recently. https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2028

Just use:

```
stack install ghc-mod-5.0.0
```

or any other version you like.